# Translate "feature" as a verb to Chinese

Tags: translation, verbs

How would one translate "feature" as verb to Chinese? 
e.g
This album features all the new artist from NYC.
or
This frying pan features all new design allows the user to cook in their sleep
..

Comment: see e。g。iciba，VERB 由…主演;以…为主要内容;重点介绍，more example sentences in jukuu

Comment: iciba 翻译：This frying pan features an all new design allowing the user to cook in their sleep－＞这个平底锅的特点是一个全新的设计，让用户在他们的睡眠中做饭。 

user suggested modification：这个平底锅的特点是个全新的设计，让用户在睡眠中做饭

Comment: Be careful, there is no general equivalent to 'to feature someone/something' in Chinese, what works in one setting will likely not work for another example.

Comment: 刻画、描写，as in “This album features all the new artist from NYC”.  拥有...的特性、功能 as in "This frying pan features..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say `以xxx为特色/特点/重点`. (or `由xxx主演` for movie etc)

> This album features all the new artist from NYC.

`该专辑以来自纽约市的所有新艺术家为特色。`

Or use `xxx的特色在于` for same meaning, sometimes make the sentence more natural.

> This frying pan features all new design allows the user to cook in their sleep.

`该平底煎锅的特色在于全新设计允许用户在睡眠中进行烹饪。`